# How to resolve pickle error in pyspark?

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode, apache-spark, pyspark

I am iterating through files to gather information about the values in their columns and rows in a dictionary.  I have the following code which works locally:

```
def search_nulls(file_name):
    separator = ','
    nulls_dict = {}
    fp = open(file_name,'r')
    null_cols = {}
    lines = fp.readlines()

    for n,line in enumerate(lines):
        line = line.split(separator)
        for m,data in enumerate(line):
            data = data.strip('\n').strip('\r')
            if str(m) not in null_cols:
                null_cols[str(m)] = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
            if len(data) <= 4:
                null_cols[str(m)][str(data)] = null_cols[str(m)][str(data)] + 1

    return null_cols


files_to_process = ['tempfile.csv']
results = map(lambda file: search_nulls(file), files_to_process)
```

The above code works fine without spark.
I comment the last two lines above, and I try with spark, since this is a prototype of something that will need to run distributed:

```
os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = <path_to_spark_folder>
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("search_files").setMaster('local')

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

objects = sc.parallelize(files_to_process)
resulting_object = \
    objects.map(lambda file_object: find_nulls(file_object))

result = resulting_object.collect()
```

When using spark, though, this results in the following error:

```
File "<path-to-spark>/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "<path-to-spark>/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "<path-to-spark>/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 267, in dump_stream
    bytes = self.serializer.dumps(vs)
  File "<path-to-spark>/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 415, in dumps
    return pickle.dumps(obj, protocol)
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found​
```

I've been unable to find any obvious reason why this would fail, since it runs perfectly locally, and I am not sharing any files across worker nodes.  In fact, I'm only running this on my local machine anyway.

Does anyone know of a good reason why this might be failing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The source of your problem is a following line:

```
null_cols[str(m)] = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
```

As you can read in the [What can be pickled and unpickled?](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) section of [the pickle module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pickle.html):

> The following types can be pickled:
>
> - ...
> - functions defined at the top level of a module (using def, not lambda)
> - built-in functions defined at the top level of a module
> - ...

It should be clear that `lambda: 0` doesn't meet above criteria. To make it work you can for example replace lambda expression with `int`:

```
null_cols[str(m)] = defaultdict(int)
```

How is it possible that we can pass lambda expression to the higher order functions in PySpark? The devil is in the detail. PySpark is using different serializers depending on a context. To serialize closures, including lambda expressions it is using custom [`cloudpickle`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/33ae7a35daa86c34f1f9f72f997e0c2d4cd8abec/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py) which supports lambda expressions and nested functions. To handle data it is using default Python tools.

---

A few side notes:

- I wouldn't use Python `file` objects to read data. It is not portable and won't work beyond local file system. You can use `SparkContex.wholeTextFiles` instead.
- if you do make sure you close the connections. Using `with` statement is usually the best approach
- you can safely strip newline characters before you split the line

Comment: So, just to clarify, generally speaking, a `lambda` function that can be serialized locally should be able to be serialized by `pyspark`?  It would be useful to know this for the purpose of testing things locally.  Thanks for your persistence on this question.

Comment: Most of the time yes. You have to think when and where things happen and generally speaking I wouldn't overuse lambdas. Pretty much all common operations can be performed using built-in functions, without static typing there are error prone, inherently not testable, and surprisingly verbose.